# Replacement for TextInputFormat in the new Hadoop API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

What is the replacement of TextInputFormat in the new Hadoop API??

When I am using TextInputFormat, I get the warning that its deprecated and I need an Input file type which treats each \n terminated line in a file as a separate value.

Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your are using the one from the mapred package. The one in the mapreduce package is the one to use.